# How to get orchestration instance server name

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk2006r2

I  have two server where orchestration can run.I need to know the server name where my orchestration instance has run .How to get this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...why?  If you have the Orchestration's Host mapped to more then on server, there is no reliable or supported way to influence that.

However, you can use any standard .Net technique to get the local computer name.  For example:

System.Environment.MachineName

Comment: Exactly.  It can be that one orchestration instance gets executed on more than one server instance.  Especially if you have persistence that trigger the orchestration to unload from memory